# fastapi блокировка выполнения запросов при вызове асинхронной функции

Tags: python, postgresql, асинхронность, fastapi

в проекте присутствует роут (`def start_ml`), который содержит в себе функцию (`main_task`) обрабатывающий видеопоток. видеопоток обрабатывается покадрово (последовательно). по мере обработки видео происходит асинхронное обновление данных в БД (postgres). пример кода:

```
@result.get("/start_algorithm/{uid}",
            tags=["execution"], status_code=200, responses=response_404_video)
async def start_ml(uid: str,  background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    query = (
        select(
            [
                video_table.c.id,
                video_table.c.path
            ]
        ).select_from(video_table).where(video_table.c.uid == uid)
    )
    data = await database.fetch_one(query)
    if data is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="video not found")
    res = await main_task(data.path, uid, data.id)
    return res
```

```
async def main_task(path_video: str, uid: str, id: int):
    data = {
        "uid": uid,
        "path": path_video,
          ...
        }
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path_video)
    q_loading = video_table.update().where(video_table.c.uid == uid).values(status="loading")
    await database.fetch_one(q_loading)
    totalFrames = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
    for _ in range(int(totalFrames)):
        _, cv2_frame = cap.read()
       ...

    q = video_table.update().where(video_table.c.uid == uid).values(status="success")
    await database.fetch_one(q)
    return data
```

при запросе на роут весь сервис API не отвечает до тех пор, пока не завершится обработка видео. ка решить данную проблему?
мои попытки:

1. `background_tasks.add_task(main_task, data.path, uid, data.id)`
2. `x = threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(data.path, uid, data.id, database,))`

в 1) все равно происходит ожидание

во 2) ошибка при выполнении `asyncpg.exceptions._base.InterfaceError: cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress`

Comment: Я бы еще multiprocessing попробовал как вариант

Comment: @insolor я реши проблему через  ```loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: asyncio.run(main_task(data.path, uid, data.id)))```. в `main_task` сделал connect к database

Comment: Я думаю имеет смысл добавить ваше решение ответом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я реши проблему через `loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: asyncio.run(main_task(data.path, uid, data.id)))`. в `main_task` сделал явный `connect` к `database`. `run_in_executor` - создает отдельный поток для задачи, ему не доступно соединение к бд